# Looping in Tkinter isnt working as I intended

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to update some buttons  at the for loop in the end, which buttons I don't want to create individually.

I tried using:

```
While True:
root.update()
```

and the other type of update and also each one individually but no luck.

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import Image
from functools import partial
import random

#define variables
#main_window_width = 500
#main_window_height = 500

#def functions
buttons_list = []

def InitButtons(n, k):
    if k == 0:
        k = n
    for i in range(n):
        InitButtons_column = i
        if i//k > 0:
            InitButtons_column = i%k
        buttons_list.append(Label(main_window, image=button_img))
        buttons_list[i].grid(row=(i//k), column=InitButtons_column)

def Hovering(e):
    button_img = PhotoImage(file = '/home/klet/Desktop/projects/Python/GUI/button2.png')
    buttons_list_button.config(image = button_img)
    buttons_list_button.image = button_img

def Clicking(e):
    button_img = PhotoImage(file = '/home/klet/Desktop/projects/Python/GUI/button3.png')
    buttons_list_button.config(image = button_img)
    buttons_list_button.image = button_img  

def NotHovering(e):
    button_img = PhotoImage(file = '/home/klet/Desktop/projects/Python/GUI/button1.png')
    buttons_list_button.config(image = button_img)
    buttons_list_button.image = button_img

def UpdatingButtons(n):
    n.bind("<Enter>", Hovering)
    n.bind("<Leave>", NotHovering)
    n.bind("<Button-1>", Clicking)
    n.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", Hovering)


root = Tk()

button_img = PhotoImage(file = "/home/klet/Desktop/projects/Python/GUI/button1.png")

main_window = Frame(root)
main_window.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)

InitButtons(10, 5)

#buttons_list_tmp1 = 0
#buttons_list_tmp1 += 1
#buttons_list_button = 
#UpdatingButtons(buttons_list_tmp1)
#print(buttons_list_tmp1)
for i in range(len(buttons_list)):
    buttons_list_button = buttons_list[i]
    UpdatingButtons(buttons_list_button)
    print(i)

root.mainloop()
```

The for loop above is only repeating once and i want it to be constantly updating, I also tried putting the whole code (within root and root.mainloop()) in a while loop but didnt work. I also searched some questions asked but they didnt seem to help.
I want to update the buttons(labels in this case) when I enter the button and when i click. Heres an example of what currently happening:
[Link to vid](https://streamable.com/c5f02z)

I made this account just to ask this question because I really dont like asking questions.

Comment: Are you sure that there are actually items in buttons_list? Try adding `global buttons_list` as the first line of the `InnitButtons` function.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having with the code?  The only thing that I see wrong is that `Hovering()`/`Clicking()`/`NotHovering()` are always working with a single button (whichever one was last assigned to `buttons_list_button`), rather than the button that actually triggered the binding (accessible as `e.widget`).

Comment: @scotty3785 I provided a vid to whats currently happening.

Comment: @jasonharper You're right. So how do I make it so they get updated individually (Im not sure I understand "accessible as e.widget")? I also provided a video to whats happening

Comment: Everywhere you currently have `buttons_list_button` in those three functions (which is a reference to a specific button, unrelated to the one that just generated an event), use `e.widget` instead.

Comment: @jasonharper You're a life saver. I've literally been trying to fix this problem since  yesterday. It works wonderfully. Thank you